# Diamond symbol in schematic

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, symbol

I am having a lot of Diamond symbols in my schematic named as Pxxxx. I am not able to find what it means as there are no legends mentioned in the file.[image]

Also, are there any general conventions that govern the usage of symbols in schematics?

Comment: It's just a net label.

Answer (score 8):

Those look to me like testpoints. On an actual board they would either be empty pads or they may actually be testpoint components.

Comment: Are test points typically indicated using this symbol?

Comment: As far as I know there is not much of a standard for test points. Usually I see them as little circles with a wire connecting to them (http://www.radio-electronics.com/images/circuit-symbol-test-point-terminal.gif) though using other symbols is not unheard of. It generally comes down to how the design engineer was trained and his/her personal preferences.

Comment: @SojuTVarghese ours look differently (sort of a triangle) and are labeled TPxx. I guess it's a company wide standard but not much more.

Answer (score 8):

I'll hazard a guess that these are [test points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_point).  These provide an convenient access to a signal.  Test points are useful for debugging, quality control testing, calibration, troubleshooting.  A signal can be probed at a test point.  Or, a test signal may be injected into a test point to exercise the downstream circuitry.

On the PCB, a test point can manifest itself differently, depending on the expected type of test.

- It can be a [throughole](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/5011/36-5011-ND/255333) of [surface-mount](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/5016/36-5016TR-ND/278887) component for clipping a probe to.
- It can be throughole for sticking an oscilloscope into.
- It can be a surface-mount pad for automated test equipment.

As far as I know, there is no single standard schematic symbol for test points.  Here are a few symbols that come with schematic software.

[image: test point symbols from OrCAD schematic capture] (from OrCAD)

[image] (from Altium)

The standard designator for test point it `TP` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator)).

Answer (score 3):

It's either a net label or a test point.

Comment: sorry, but i don't get what a net label is..?

Comment: A net label is simply a way of naming a net (a connection). This is especially useful if the net has a special function and you want the reader to know what it does, or in CAD work it is used for error checking and for converting a schematic to a PCB design (showing where components connect)

Comment: A net label just assigns a name to that wire so it can be referred to later on another sheet, on reports, in simulation, during board layout, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The test points could document locations for probing on a bed of nails functional/ICT fixture defined by a Test Engineer working with the Design Engineer for high fault coverage for fixture design.