# What is the significance of this symbol?

Tags: symbol

What the significance of this symbol?

[image]

It's part of 17IPS61-3 26" to 40" LED Slim Integrated Power Supply, and the whole datasheet can be found [here](http://mharding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Power-Supply-17IPS61-3-VESTEL.pdf).

Comment: That whole schematic is strange.

Comment: @RobertEndl  do you mean this symbol isn't standard ?

Comment: That looks like it could be a [test point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_point).

Comment: With the data sheet, there should be an explanation of the symbols...

Comment: There should be but there isn't. It's a reasonable question. +1 to counter the negative votes. What is an "alimentation"?

Comment: @Transistor thank you :) "Alimentation" was a little french mistake, corrected

Comment: @ snoop dog  The odd symbols might mean test points.  However, the schematic has series/parallel resisters and parallel diodes.  Not my first design choices.  Also, connecting the grounds through transformer windings…I have not seen that before.

Comment: @Robert Endl, This is a Power Supply card that found frequently inside TV screen. I believe it is really common. One of the diode was dead, I read it's often the case with this card, could that design explains it ? Also, yes it's definitely test points, these are clearly visible on the circuit board, now I understand it.

Comment: @ snoop dogg  Yes, silicon diodes don't share current well.  The temperature slope of the forward voltage drop goes the wrong way.  The use of many resisters might be a cost decision...many small resisters might be cheaper than one big one.

Comment: Those are the on-chip fans. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Further to Billy and Trevor's test-point suggestion, the test points may be designed for a pogo-pin test fixture and some special PCB "pad" assigned for the function.

[image]

*Figure 1. A PCB test fixture with pogo-pins allows simultaneous and rapid connection to multiple points on the circuit. Source: Spehro Pefhany's answer to [Is there such a thing as a pin (or pogo pin) clamp for testing?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163550/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pin-or-pogo-pin-clamp-for-testing).*

Such a system might, for example, allow automated testing of your power-supply board under various conditions such as lower and upper limits of the supply voltage, no-load, half-load and full load on the output and testing control inputs and monitoring outputs. When I first saw National Instruments equipment thirty years ago this seemed to be a large part of their business.

[image]

*Figure 2. Pogo-pin test pads on a PCB. The quantity of test pads in this case suggests that the designer is not all that confident!*

See [What parts would one typically use for automated PCB testing?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79224/what-parts-would-one-typically-use-for-automated-pcb-testing) for more details and photos of pogo-pin types.

Comment: The number of pogo-pin test pads in the above image is *very unlikely* to have anything to to with the designer's confidence (in whatever). It's not uncommon to have a design-for-manufacturing requirement that *all* signals on the board (or a specified subset) have test pads. This is what appears to be happening on the board in the image. Such capability is used for a variety of types of testing in various stages of manufacturing. Much, but certainly not all, of these uses are supplanted by the use of JTAG for many designs.

Comment: IMO, implying that the number of test points has anything to do with the designer's confidence is counter productive. It disparages the use of test points, when how many to use and in what way is a *normal engineering decision*. It's one that often involves multiple considerations (layout, your manufacturing process, etc.).

Comment: [Similar question about test a point symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/254831/7036)

Answer (score 4):

I would also guess these are test points.

Moreover, the test point may also include a via to bring a trace through to a pad on the other side of the board to facilitate one-sided testing. Looking at the schematic as a whole, there are a spattering of them but not on every trace. That suggests the other traces are already visible from the test side. These test pads are probably inserted by the PCB designer.